# Deducing increase of mass of moving particle from modified second law

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, mass, mass-energy

I want to deduce relation $m={m_0}\gamma$ from modified second law $F = \frac{d(mv)}{dt}$ where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}$ and $c=1$.

let a mass with rest mass $m_0$ be at rest in frame $S'$ which moves with velocity $v$ in $x$ direction from frame $S$ and we want to see what is its mass in frame $S$.

Let a very weak rocket which works for small time $\Delta t$ and produces small force $\Delta F$ in frame which started at rest. "If" we turn it on on a mass $m_0$ in $x$-direction in frame $S$ the velocity of mass in $S$ after this becomes say $u$. Now turn on the rocket in $x$-direction on a mass $m_0$ rested in $S'$ now velocity of mass in $S'$ frame becomes $u$, but $S$ say the rocket was on for time $\gamma\Delta t$. so turn on rocket only for $\frac{\Delta t}{\gamma}$ seconds and velocity of mass in $S'$ becomes $\frac{u}{\gamma}$.

Now velocity in frame $S$ becomes $\frac{\frac{u}{\gamma}+v}{1+\frac{u}{\gamma}v}$ which exceeds $v$ by
$$\frac{\frac{u}{\gamma}+v}{1+\frac{u}{\gamma}v}-v 
= \frac{u}{\gamma}\frac{1-v^2}{1+\frac{u}{\gamma}v}
 = \frac{u}{\gamma^3}\frac{1}{1+\frac{u}{\gamma}v}\approx \frac{u}{\gamma^3}$$
(because rocket is very weak and so $u<<1$). Now neglect increase in mass of the considered mass by turning on rocket because we now from daily experiments that such a weak rocket almost doesn't increases mass but almost only the velocity.

Now the mass when had velocity $v$ by same force had $\gamma^3$times less increase in velocity than if it was at rest (as observed by $S$). So moving mass by velocity $v$ in $\gamma^3$times heavier!!

How could such a deduction modified to give true result $\gamma$? if couldn't why? and could we have such a rocket base deduction? and if couldn't, could we deduce increase in mass somehow from almost only from modified second law?

Answer (score 1):

The relationship $m=m_0\gamma$ is usually obtained by considering inelastic collision and applying the conservation of momentum.

It applies to two frames that have *constant* relative velocity. When you add acceleration into the same direction as that velocity and apply Newton's second law the factor $\gamma^3$ pops up inevitably. See the concept of [longitudinal mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Transverse_and_longitudinal_mass) which has riddled Einstein and Lorentz but is no longer very popular nowadays.